# certificate error while subdomain forwarding

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have a website, call it http://sub.example.com, hosted on, say, 72.xx.xx.x.  There is a certificate for https://sub.example.com.

Now I go into the DNS management tool in my hosting provider, and I set up the standard subdomain forwarding wherein https://sub.example.com forwards to 72.xx.xx.x.

Now when I try to browse to https://sub.example.com, I get a certificate error saying it is for the wrong website.

I have also tried forwarding http://sub.example.com to 72.xx.xx.x, and tried it with domain masking in both cases.  I am still getting the certificate error no matter what.

Additional wrinkle: if someone types in https://sub.example.com then the domain forwarding does not seem to work and IE just spins endlesssly and finally fails.

How can I domain forward the https://sub.example.com to 72.xx.xx.x?

Comment: Need more details, like *exactly* what the error message is and what the subject of the SSL cert is.

Comment: And the fact that serverfault won't let you post it there doesn't mean if belongs here. You can use some escaping syntax to prevent the link-like text from being hyperlinked, since they don't actually go anywhere.

Comment: What exactly is the certificate error saying?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I have a website call it http://subdomain.mydomain.com hosted on say 72.xx.xx.x

So why would you setup additional subdomain forwarding for https?  Name resolution is done independently of the protocol. There is no need for another DNS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the diff is maybe someone here can help but I basically deleted the subdomain and created an A record and everything worked like a charm
Thanks